# SQL find dates in 31 day timeframe

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a list of dates and need to find the first date that occurs within a 31 day timeframe:

```
ID       Date
101     6/8/16
101     10/27/16
101     11/25/16
101     12/14/16
101     1/1/17
101     1/7/17
101     2/1/17
```

Since the first date occurs on 6/8/16, that would be the 'anchor' date. 6/8/16 would count as the first date in the 31 day period (6/8/16 - 7/8/16), and then find the first date occurring on or between 7/9/16 and 8/8/16 if they have one, between 8/9/16 - 9/8/16, and so on. Also, all these dates need to be between Jan 1 and Dec 1 of each year so 12/14/16 is excluded. Thanks in advance.

The output for this would be:

```
ID      Date
101    6/8/16
101    10/27/16
101    11/25/16
101    1/1/17
101    2/1/17
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why `12/14/16` is exclude it? btw always try use ansi notation for dates  `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You can use the `DATEADD()` as well as the `DATEPART()` function in order to get pieces of your dates like the day or month.  For example, if you want the first date + 31 days, you could do `SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 31, CAST('6/8/16' as datetime))`  The DATEPART() function will return parts of a date like the day, dayofweek, month, or year.  Why are dates from within december to be excluded?

Comment: Is there any sequence number in this table which guarantees order?

Comment: this makes no sense what so ever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row calculate the difference to the min date and divide it by 31 to create those 31 day periods. Then get the min date of each period. To exclude those date from december you can calculate MMDD and add a WHERE-condition:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT id, date,
      datediff(day, Min(date) Over (partition by id), date) / 31 AS period
   FROM vt
   WHERE datepart(m, date) * 100 + datepart(d, date) 
      BETWEEN 0101 AND 1201
 )
SELECT id, Min(date)
FROM cte
GROUP BY id, period
```